# Wi-Fi does not work on Asus k450j

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, ethernet

I started using Ubuntu very recently. I get no wireless connection on Ubuntu, but it works on Windows. I have already checked for Wifi boot when powered on BIOS, but there's  no option like that so I guess it must be a driver problem.

MY wifi device:

produto: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros

My laptop Asus k450j

```
rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: 

<iwconfig>

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions

<ifconfig>

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW PRIVATE
          inet end.: PRIVATE  Bcast:PRIVATE  Masc:PRIVATE
          endereço inet6: PRIVATE Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:167351 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:42874 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:241203107 (241.2 MB) TX bytes:3552425 (3.5 MB)
          IRQ:19 

lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:3236 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:3236 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:384735 (384.7 KB) TX bytes:384735 (384.7 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.